# render components conditionally base on localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, jsx

this is my code , I am try to render my screens container div base on token saved in localStorage, I use useState to save my token but when you logOut or logIn you need to refresh, I do not know how to useEffect here to re-render base on localStorage.
I want to whenever user logged in or logged out my app component get rendered .

```
function App() {
  const [isloggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(localStorage.getItem("token"));
return (
   
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/login"
            element={<Login />}
          />
        </Routes>

        {isloggedIn && <div className="screens-container">
            <Sidebar />}
          <div className="screens-section-container">
            <Navbar />
            <Routes>
              <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
                <Route
                  element={<Home />}
                  path="/"
                  exact
                />
              </Route>
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </div>}
      </BrowserRouter>
   
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`isLoggedIn` state will not re-render but only on page initial render it will look for `token` localStorage state .

You need to change the state itself and a recommended way is like this :

```
const App: FC<AppProps> = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState<boolean>(false);

   const checkToken = () => {
     const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
     if (token) setIsLoggedIn(true);
     else {
       setIsLoggedIn(false);
     }
   };

   useEffect(() => {
     checkToken();
   }, []);

  const handleAuth = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      setIsLoggedIn(false);
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem("token", "123");
      setIsLoggedIn(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={handleAuth}>{isLoggedIn ? "Sign out" : "Login"}</button>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This way on page first render , the `useEffect` hook will run on component mount and it will check for localStorage `token` state and change the `isLoggedIn` state and later If we remove `token` from localStorage , `isLoggedIn` state will change accordingly .

**NOTE**

In real world projects , we never handle authentication like this . Using a state management system like Redux and React Context is highly recommended .